# Configuring Apache Tomcat to forward requests to Mongrel

Tags: ruby, tomcat, mongrel

Is there a way of configuring Tomcat to forward all requests of a certain pattern (eg www.my_company.com/my_ruby_app) to Mongrel?

Right now I'm trying to play around with Tomcat's server.xml file, specifically with the Service, Connector and Engine tags.  If anyone knows of any resources I'd love to hear about them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about Tomcat to know how to forward requests. However, depending on your use case, you can actually mount a Ruby on Rails application in Tomcat using JRuby and the warbler gem.  If you can use JRuby for this project, I recommend this option.

More on warbler:  http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/

More on JRuby:    http://jruby.org/

Comment: Thanks Shawn...I've come across some JRuby links.  And if possible I would like to stick to writing everything in Ruby, but if not then JRuby and warbler might be the way to go.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you'd like to stick to MRI?  JRuby tends to be very solid.  That said, there are some gems that require C extensions that may not work with JRuby, but most gems work without issue.

Comment: Actually, do you not have anything sitting in front of Tomcat like nginx or Apache?  If you do, then you should focus on proxy passing in those, not Tomcat.

Comment: Hi Sean, Unfortunately no...there's nothing sitting in front of Tomcat.  I see quite a few articles for Apache but not for Apache Tomcat.  I'm looking at warbler documentation right now and it seems pretty promising.  I'll let you know how it all goes.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So I used the warbler gem and it's working perfectly.  Now I have another error to face with Apache Tomcat (ie "We're sorry, but something went wrong.")  =)  Thanks again Sean!